# How to obtain a field from my test in a Junit 5 jupiter extension

Tags: java, junit5, junit-jupiter

I have a Custom tag for my tests for a driver ive created. Im looking for a way to initialize and quit this driver during the BeforeEach and the AfterEach, using the new Junit5 jupiter extensions.

```
@Target({TYPE, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@ExtendWith(MyExtension.class)
public @interface MyDriver
{
}
```

I've seen there is a AnnotationSupport.class that should help you to obtain the fields annotated with certain annotation but havent found any example.

What I want is just to be able to work with the field annotated with my annotation from the extension.

Comment: Do you know of the classes in which the fields annotated with this will be present?

Comment: @AdwaitKumar yes, all of my testing clases will have them for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go about it like this:

```
public class MyExtension implements BeforeEachCallback {
    @Override
    public void beforeEach(ExtensionContext context)  {
        context.getTestInstance().ifPresent(testInstance -> {
            List<Field> driverFields = AnnotationSupport.findAnnotatedFields(testInstance.getClass(), MyDriver.class);
            for (Field driverField : driverFields) {
                try {
                    Object fieldValue = driverField.get(testInstance);
                    // Do whatever you want with the field or its value
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Which would then be called before each test in a test class like this:

```
@MyDriver
class SomeTestThatUsesDriver {

    @MyDriver
    Object fieldWithAnnotation = "whatever";

    @Test
    void aTest() {
       ...
    }
}
```

What I wouldn't do, though, is to use the annotation `@MyDriver` for both adding the extension and marking a field. I'd rather got with an additional annotation like `@MyDriverField` or add the extension directly at the test class.

Comment: Thank you, with this you solve my problem and make better my driver. What i've done is what you said and instead of creating an Annotation that extends the extension is add the extension with extendsWith on top of the classes i need.